# こぇのか instead of こわいのか

Tags: colloquial-language

I have two questions regarding this.

1) Since, modern Japanese doesn't have a "we" character, they use "ぇ", right? I've heard many shows where they say "suge! yabe!" but is "koe" used often? I said I wanted to use this "こぇのか" instead of the "こわいのか" because I wanted to make it sound slangy and informal.

2) is the の necessary in these sentences, if we were to remove it, can we still get the same meaning?
Like, "こわいのか" translates to "Are you scared?", so we remove the "の" in this and hence we get, "こわいか" Does this still mean "Are you scared?"

Answer (score 2):

As you may have noticed, there are various slangy forms of regular adjectives such as:

格好いい　→　かっけえ／かっけぇ

凄い　　　→　すげー／すげえ／すげぇ

悪い　　　→　わりい／わりぃ

怖い　　　→　こわぇ／こええ

If you type either こわえ or こええ, you will get a suggestion for 怖え／恐え.

As for の, remember that it's just a different form of こと, so it is optional in this case because the meaning doesn't change much.

怖いのか？　→　Are you scared?

怖いか？　　→　Scared?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, こええ is commonly used in slang/informal speech.
2. Yes, the meaning doesn't change, but simply adding か to informal sentences is very informal(might even come off as being rude). So, you might wanna avoid using it.

edit: Regarding your 'we' question, there is ヴェ and ウェ which would sound like 'we'.

Answer (score 0):

> 2) is the の necessary in these sentences, if we were to remove it, can we still get the same meaning? Like, "こわいのか" translates to "Are you scared?", so we remove the "の" in this and hence we get, "こわいか" Does this still mean "Are you scared?"

The の indicates there is a context to the question, that it is based on some observation of the situation. For example your hands are shaking, are you scared or are you just cold?

> こわいのか

On the other hand, without the の there is less context. I feel scared, and I'm wondering if you are too:

> こわいか